# Can I adjust the cooking time and temperature for my braise?

Tags: oven, temperature, beef, braising

My recipe says to braise beef in the oven at 180 C/350 F for 1.5 hours. Dinner is in about four hours. Can I also get away with sticking the dish into the oven at a lower temperature (say 150 C/300 F or 120 C/250 F) and expect it to be just done for dinner? If so, to which temperature should I set my oven? Is there any way I can convert or calculate this myself?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be too late for you, but in general a braise can be done at a lower temperature as long as the food doesn't stay in the "danger zone" for too long.  See [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat/34671#34671) for more information on the danger zone.

For example, [this recipe](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-braise-meat-995850) advise to have the oven at 300 F for an and hour per pound.  In the tips section, it states that the author sometimes drops the temp to 250 F.

Braising is fairly forgiving and is typically a method used on tougher cuts of meat, so going slightly longer shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the "danger zone", and how can I figure out when my meat will reach it?

Comment: I edited the post to add [this link](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat/34671#34671) to more information on the danger zone.

Comment: Hi @LittleMsWhoops, the danger zone is a basic concept of food safety. We have written up a short explanation of how food safety works under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info, you may want to read it.